# make a nice url of the page - I get an error 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, mysqli

this is how I'm going to order made ​​so that I have a nice url of the page

This is how the problem is just the moment so I get an error 404 it will not catch up content on the site in some way at all.

**.htaccess** here:

```
RewriteRule ^nyhed-side/([^/.])/$ /artikler-indhold.php?url=$2
```

here import im title til the site **mysqli/php**

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT title FROM artikler WHERE url = ?')) { 
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $url);
        $url = $_GET["url"];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($title);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo $title;
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

You can show its [here](http://www.ordklar.dk/nyhed/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to incorrect regex in your rule.

Change that to:

```
RewriteRule ^nyhed-side/([^/.]*)/?$ /artikler-indhold.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Your regex is matching only single character after `/nyhed-side/`

Comment: Now it not coming error 404., and why not work my php / mysqli code more?

Comment: Before mysqi code just print `echo $_GET['url'];` to make sure you get right value.

Comment: Change $2 to $1 in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

you are calling $url before you have declared it.

swap these two lines around:

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $url);
$url = $_GET["url"];
```

Comment: I think $2 should also be $1